# li postion one after another and marquee effect left(without using plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to play maquee effect back to back li.
I not be able to place the li's in horizontal.

like this

```
 text.. text.. text.. text.. text..
```

as a example of code:

```
<div>

    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>
    <li>text...........</li>

</div>
```

in Li there will be paragraph and table tag so contain will b big.
if you have alternate solution for this reply.

Thank you for reply..

Comment: To much going wrong here... Please correct your HTML markup as it is invalid (LI cannot go inside a SPAN or a DIV). Also, please show us some sample code of what you've tried so far. SO is not some kind of coding service where you just get what you ask for...

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Brother,
You have to use < ul > or < ol > instead

and you also have to edit the css of the element "ul/ol"

You should do something like that

```
<style rel="stylesheet">
    li{display:inline;}
</style>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>test3</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanx for reply. but if i add more li its comes down

Comment: I'm sorry the correct for CSS is: li{display:inline} not ul{dislay:inline}

Comment: in marquee effect the first li and last li shows together.

Comment: I think you could put each < li > a fixed width, and put the < ul > a sum of all the < li >'s width. I don't know if I understood haha.

Comment: that also i tried but if the li is increase its comes down.

Comment: hmmmm, I've found one thing here maybe helps, add on style this:    ul{white-space: nowrap;}

Comment: Tell me one thing. The marqee tag's working? I have been noticed that the new browsers' not working with that anymore. If this is true, i need to find other way to do that, something like javascrit.

Answer (score 0):

1. wrap you `li` elements in an ordered/unordered list.
2. use `display:inline-block` or `float:left` for `li` elements